# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError at ClassLoader.java:2458 when I commit to pipeline of gitlab

Tags: java, gradle, gitlab, unsatisfiedlinkerror

When running it on my IDE, the tests passes without failing. But when I've committed it to a repository, the pipeline raises this error for all of the tests.

I'm testing my client scenes with TestFX, Mockito and JUnit 5.

```
JoinPageCtrlTest > testClearFields() FAILED
    java.lang.RuntimeException at WaitForAsyncUtils.java:301
        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException at QuantumToolkit.java:300
            Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError at ClassLoader.java:2458
```

My test class

```
package client.scenes;

import client.utils.ServerUtils;
import jakarta.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import commons.Event;

import org.testfx.framework.junit5.ApplicationTest;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

public class JoinPageCtrlTest extends ApplicationTest {

    @Mock
    private ServerUtils server;

    @Mock
    private MainCtrl mainCtrl;

    @InjectMocks
    private JoinPageCtrl joinPageCtrl;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        joinPageCtrl = new JoinPageCtrl(server, mainCtrl);

        TextField testEvent =
            new TextField();
        testEvent.setText("Test Event");

        TextField testJoinCode =
            new TextField();
        testJoinCode.setText("123456");

        joinPageCtrl.setEventName(testEvent);
        joinPageCtrl.setJoinCode(testJoinCode);
    }
    @Test
    public void testClearFields() {
        joinPageCtrl.clear();

        assertEquals("", joinPageCtrl.getEventName());
        assertEquals("", joinPageCtrl.getJoinCode());
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreateSuccess() {
        Event event = new Event("Test Event");
        joinPageCtrl.create();

        verify(server, times(1)).addEvent(event);
        verify(mainCtrl, times(1)).showEvent(event);
    }
    @Test
    public void testCreateFail(){
        String invalidCode = "Invalid code";
        TextField invalid = new TextField();
        invalid.setText("Invalid code");
        joinPageCtrl.setJoinCode(invalid);
        when(server.getEvent(invalidCode))
            .thenThrow(WebApplicationException.class);

        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            joinPageCtrl.join();

            verify(server, times(1))
                .getEvent(invalidCode);

            verify(mainCtrl, never()).showEvent(any(Event.class));
        });
    }
    @Test
    public void testNullCreate(){
        TextField invalid = new TextField();
        invalid.setText(null);
        joinPageCtrl.setJoinCode(null);

        doThrow(NullPointerException.class)
            .when(server).addEvent(null);

        assertThrows(NullPointerException.class, () -> joinPageCtrl.create());
    }

    @Test
    public void testJoinSuccess() {
        String joinCode = "123456";
        Event event = new Event("Test Event");
        when(server.getEvent(joinCode)).thenReturn(event);

        joinPageCtrl.join();

        verify(server, times(1)).getEvent(joinCode);
        verify(mainCtrl, times(1)).showEvent(event);
    }

    @Test
    public void testJoinFail(){
        String invalidCode = "Invalid code";
        TextField invalid = new TextField();
        invalid.setText(invalidCode);
        joinPageCtrl.setJoinCode(invalid);
        Mockito.when(server.getEvent(invalidCode))
            .thenThrow(WebApplicationException.class);

        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            joinPageCtrl.join();

            verify(server, times(1))
                .getEvent(invalidCode);

            verify(mainCtrl, never()).showEvent(any(Event.class));
        });
    }

    @Test
    public void testNullJoinCode(){
        TextField invalid = new TextField();
        invalid.setText(null);
        joinPageCtrl.setJoinCode(null);

        doThrow(NullPointerException.class)
            .when(server).getEvent(null);

        assertThrows(NullPointerException.class, () -> joinPageCtrl.join());
    }
}
```

I've tried changing a few of the tests, but I still kept getting this error. I find it weird, since it works in my IDE but not on the pipeline of my repository.